# Python web scraping with requests and beatiful soup

Tags: web, web-scraping

Help me , please. Is there any way to parse my own page of products on amazon or on other websites

When i am trying to parse any data from pages, it works. But i cant parse my own page of products i have bought. I have used requests and beautiful soup

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour], read [ask] and also how to create [mcve],so that we can reproduce your issue easily.  Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.